# Working out age based on start date month

Tags: excel

I employ a lot of employees and I need a month on month view of their age ranges and gender so I can track on a monthly basis how many I employ.

```
****************************************************
*   Name  *    Age    *   Gender   *  Start Date  *
****************************************************
*  John   *     23    *     M      *  21/02/2016  *
* Jessica *     57    *     F      *  21/02/2016  *
****************************************************
```

Then I break it down in a table like this:

```
***********
* Feb-16  *
***********************
*   Name  *    Gender *
***********************
*  16-18  *     0     *
*  18-24  *     1     *
*  24-50  *     0     *
*  50+    *     1     *
***********************
```

I know I can use `COUNT` to make general counting between ages but I need the age to be based in the month they started. I have played around with `SUMPRODUCT` but I don't understand it enough to make it work. Any guidance would be great

Comment: Am I right in assuming that what you mean is the age considered by the count needs to add on the difference in time between now and when they started?

Comment: Hi, well the age wont change as my Age formula already works off their DOB and Start Date. I'm just looking at something that filters their age by anyone who started in a particular month e.g. Feb-16

Comment: Ah, so you're looking for how to incorporate a date range into a WHERE clause, then?

Comment: Hi, that sounds about right

Comment: SELECT COUNT(age) WHERE age BETWEEN 16 AND 18 AND startDate BETWEEN #mm/dd/yyyy# AND #mm/dd/yyyy#; or something similar for whatever filtering you need.

Comment: Hi, thanks but I need to convert that into an excel formula

Comment: Gah, sorry, I've been working with SQL all morning and have it on the brain. One sec.

Comment: Have you tried a pivot table?

Comment: Hi, Pivot tables are an option but I would like it to be static

Answer (score 0):

Use COUNTIFS, which will allow you to have multiple criteria:

```
=(COUNTIFS(cellrange,"criterion",cellrange,"criterion",cellrange,"criterion"))
```

For example, using your sample data

```
=(COUNTIFS(C2:C3,"m",D2:D3,">=21/02/2016",D2:D3,"<=28/02/2016"))
```

Would show a count of all male employees who started between the 21st and 28th of February 2016. (the cell ranges are just from my Excel sheet, substitute as needed)

Comment: Can you show me your sheet and what formula you tried?